# Automatically set file attributes in a given directory

Tags: ext3, xattr

Let's say I want to set one or more attributes (in the `chattr` sense) on every file created in a given directory. 
Is there a way to achieve this automatically, like `umask` does for file permissions ?

In other words, is there a way to omit the `chattr` step in :

```
$ copy file /path/to/backup/
$ chattr +i /path/to/backup/file
```

for every file created in `/path/to/backup/` ?

Note : My system is Debian and my filesystem is ext3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run inoticoming to watch for files placed in the directory and automatically run any command, in this case chattr. (note linux specific)